# Include a Laravel blade view's section only

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade

Is there a way to include a Laravel blade view's section *only*?

---

I have a base view and usually include content inside this view. Sometimes I need a bit more freedom and want a more simple base, so I set the `$special` flag to true. Now I have a view that may both be present as a "special" and normal view. Is there a neat way to DRY this?

`base.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@yield("title", "placeholder") - website</title>
</head>
<body>
    @if (isset($special) && $special)
        @yield("content")
    @else
        <header>
            website
        </header>
        <main>
            @yield("content")
        </main>
        <footer>&copy; 2099</footer>
    @endif
</body>
</html>
```

`article.blade.php`

```
@extends("base")

@section("title", "10 ways! You won't follow the last!")

@section("content")
So much content.
@endsection
```

`other.blade.php`

```
@extends("base", ["special" => true])

@section("title", "Welcome")

@section("content")
<div id="start">
    Other stuff
</div>
<div id="wooo">
    <main>
        @include("article") ← does not work
    </main>
    <footer>&copy; 2099</footer>
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a new blade file that includes only the section. Then both pages include that blade template.

`article.blade.php`

```
@extends("base")

@section("title", "10 ways! You won't follow the last!")

@section("content")
@include("common")
@endsection
```

`other.blade.php`

```
@extends("base", ["special" => true])

@section("title", "Welcome")

@section("content")
<div id="start">
    Other stuff
</div>
<div id="wooo">
    <main>
        @include("common")
    </main>
    <footer>&copy; 2099</footer>
</div>
@endsection
```

`common.blade.php`

```
So much content.
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this like so:

I create a `base.blade.php` that contains the core things of the layout.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    @yield('body-content')

</body>
</html>
```

And then I create other templates, that extend the base file.

For example:
`template.blade.php`

```
@extends('base')

@section('body-content')

    <header>
        website
    </header>
    <main>
        @yield("content")
    </main>
    <footer>&copy; 2099</footer>

@endsection
```

`someOtherTemplate.blade.php`

```
@extends('base')

@section('body-content')
    <main>
        @yield("content")
    </main>
@endsection
```

Now just extend whichever template you need.